# SQL Query that returns "Hello" [column_name]

Tags: postgresql

How do I update this query:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users
```

To return: 'Hello, [firstname] [lastname]!'

Comment: `'Hello, ' +firstname+' '+lastname+'!'`

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used. Note that the answer will depend on it!

Comment: @Pரதீப்: that's invalid (standard) SQL. The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Originally there was a sql server tag, and those square brackets hacked my mind to believe its `sql server`

Comment: This question is too basic and a simple google search will provide answers. These kind of questions should not be encouraged and should be removed from SO to keep the quality of Q & A high and professional. Sorry, I am not trying to be rude, just encouraging people to do some research before looking for help.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new here so I don't know how to use this site well

Comment: Now add the tag for the dbms you're using! (And you'll probably soon have the answer.)

Comment: @Pரதீப் can someone use CONCAT in the query ?

Comment: @amonoff yes you can, check my answer below

Comment: I understand that such a manual can be intimidating at the beginning, but reading and it is really an essential skill you will need as a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat()` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) which adds two or more expressions together.

```
SELECT concat('Hello, ', firstname, ' ', lastname, '!') FROM users;
```

Comment: @amonoff please be aware that SQL dialects differ, ie PostGre can be very different than Oracle etc.